# Finding sum of consecutive values from a list

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

I'd like to improve my algo to find out the (sub)sum of consecutive values from the list. The function will return match as a double index, where the first value is the starting point of values, and the second value is the endpoint of values, where the searched sum can be generated.

```
// f=find sum value, a=list of values
function findConsecutiveSum(f, a) {

  var r = []; // result
  var b = []; // lookback values
  var s = 0;  // current sum
  var i = 0;  // index
  var l = a.length; // length of list

    // look back when sum (s) exceeds find sum value (f)
  function lookback() {
    // first value from lookback list
    var m = b.shift();
    while (m) {
      s -= m;
      if (s > 0) {
        if (s == f) {
          r.push([i-b.length, i]);
          b = []; s = 0;
          break;
        } else {
          m = b.shift();
        }
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
    // loop over all values from the list starting from beginning
  while (i<l) {
    s += a[i];
    // match found
    if (s == f) {
      r.push([i-b.length, i]);
      b = []; s = 0;
    // sum bigger than matched value
    } else if (s > f) {
      lookback();
      // if sum is not 0 after lookback, then add current value to lookback list
      if (s) b.push(a[i]);
    // sum smaller than matched value
    } else {
      b.push(a[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  // end of the original list is reached, but we still might need to look back
  if (b.length) lookback();
  return r;
}
```

To test and debug I use this snippet:

```
// debug, changes index range to actual values and check the sum
function checkResult(result, a, f) {
    return result.map(function(item) {
    var s = a[item[0]];
    var b = a[item[0]];
    for (var i=item[0]; i<item[1]; i++) {
        // real sum
        s += a[i+1];
      b += '+'+a[i+1];
    }
    return b+'='+s+(f==s ? ' true'  : ' false');
  });
}

// find value
var f = 5;
// find value by consecutive sum of the given list
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2];
// result is a list of index range of values, that match sum value (f)
var result = findConsecutiveSum(f, a);
// debug -> Array [ "2+3=5", "5=5", "5=5", "5=5", "2+1+2=5" ]
console.log(checkResult(result, a, f));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markokram/ffnwts5f/)

In addition:

- Negative values are not accepted, zeros are accepted.
- Note that summation is reset after a match is found, then search continues from the current position. Another option could be to not reset summation and to continue search from the last lookback position. An example is shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/markokram/ffnwts5f/5/).

Comment: Sure, I chose to use short variable names at some point, but evidently they require some comments for easier review :)

Comment: What happens in the case of `var a = [4, 1, 4]; var f = 5;` ? Do you intend to get [0, 1], [1, 2] or just [0, 1]?

Comment: My additional info part 2 deals with the question. Given code on OT results only the second of your solutions, which is ok and my default use case. My other jsfiddle#5 takes care of both possibilities with an additional argument. Good point.

Comment: With non-negative values only, this looks simple: from an index _start_, accumulate until the _target_ value is reached (→output) or exceeded. While _target_ is exceeded, subtract the value at _start_ and increment _start_. Repeat until exhausted.